# Associate multiple commands to multiple buttons using forloop - tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, tkinter, tk-toolkit

In the following code, 3 buttons are created and associated with 3 different actions.Now each button has to perform their action.

```
import tkinter as tk

class App():
    def __init__(self,parent):
        self.parent = parent
        self.do_oper()


    def do_oper(self):
        self.labelframe = tk.Frame(self.parent).grid()
        m = ['a','b','c']
        n = ['self.a','self.b','self.c']
        dict_cmds = dict(zip(m,n))
        for i,cmd in enumerate(dict_cmds):
            self.Label=tk.Button(self.labelframe,command=lambda cmd=cmd:dict_cmds[cmd])
            self.Label.config(text=cmd)
            self.Label.grid(row=1,column=i)


    def a(self):
        print('Inside -> a')

    def b(self):
        print('Inside -> b')

    def c(self):
        print('Inside -> c')

if __name__ =='__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    App(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `dict_cmds = {'a': self.a, 'b': self.b, 'c': self.c}`, `tk.Button(self.labelframe, command=dict_cmds[cmd])`

Comment: I had tried that earlier, that did not work

Comment: yes it did, thank you. But when i zip two lists to a dict, how can i remove the string from it

Comment: Is there a reason why you're storing them as strings? It'd be __much__ better to reference the functions directly.

Comment: yes, the reason is i'm zipping all my images list with functions which are in another list. Is there an alternative for that

Comment: I don't see how the images are related to the problem. Is there a reason why your list is `['self.a','self.b']` and not `[self.a, self.b]`? If the list is created without access to a `self`, it could still be `[App.a, App.b]`.

Comment: yea i got that...thanks